# Laravel selectRaw omits appended columns

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

Why is that laravel/eloquent/db omits my appended columns when i try to use raw sql?

Is there any other way to use groupBy and aggregate the result using eloquent that can retain my appended columns?

I have an appended column in my model class

```
public function getWorkAttribute()
{
    switch ($this->work_tag) {
        case self::WORK_CREATIVE:
            return trans('unit_time.work.creative');
        case self::WORK_DEV:
            return trans('unit_time.work.dev');
        case self::WORK_QA:
            return trans('unit_time.work.qa');
        case self::WORK_REVIEW:
            return trans('unit_time.work.review');
    }
}
```

This is how i fetched the data from my repository

```
public function getTeamMembersWithoutTask($team_id)
{
    $assigned_units = $this->getTeamAssignedUnits($team_id);
    $ids = $assigned_units->pluck('employee_id');

    return UnitTime::selectRaw('unit_id, employee_id, MAX(updated_at) as updated_at')
        ->where('team_id', $team_id)
        ->whereNotIn('employee_id', $ids)
        ->groupBy('employee_id')
        ->orderBy('updated_at', 'asc')
        ->get();
}
```

But when i try to check if also returns my appended column, it just return null

```
$members_without_task = $team_repo->getTeamMembersWithoutTask($team->id);

foreach ($members_without_task as $member) {
    var_dump($member->work);
}
```

Result:

```
null
null
null
null
null
null
```

Answer (score 2):

I just found out the answer myself, you need to include the columns that the appended column use in order for it to have its output

```
UnitTime::selectRaw('unit_id, work_tag, action_tag, employee_id, MAX(updated_at) as updated_at')
```